# What is the setting to increase the aggregating of ratings?

Tags: content-rating

I see this only occurs about every hour, and I would like to increase the frequency. Seems to confuse users that they don't see ratings right away. Which service would this setting be located in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey,
There are essentially two services that you need to enable:

1. User Profile Service Application - Social Data Maintenance Job
2. User Profile Service Application - Social Rating Synchronization Job

This should help you out, my good friend Charles has an awesome post on the whole thing that you can check out at: http://www.habaneros.com/blog/10-01-22/SharePoint_2010_User_Profile_Synchronization.aspx